# jquery selecting/unselecting checkboxes in children/parent <li>

Tags: .net, jquery, checkbox, html-lists

I have the following

```
<ul>
   <li>Main
    <ul>
        <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" /> parent 1
           <ul>
               <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" />sub 1</li>
               <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" />sub 2
                  <ul>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" />sub sub 2</li>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" />sub sub 3</li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
            </ul> 
        </li>
        <li><input type="checkbox" onclick="$.SelectChildren(this);" />parent 2</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
```

Now for my JQuery function:

```
(function ($) {
    $.SelectChildren = function (element) {
        if ($(element).is(':checked')) {
            $(element).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', true);
        }
        else {
            $(element).parent().find(':checkbox').attr('checked', false);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

how would I unselect ONLY (all)parent checkboxes when un-checking a child

for example: when clicked "sub sub 2" checkbox -> it should uncheck "sub 2" and "parent 1" checkboxes as well.

thanks

Comment: consider marking answers that solve your problems as accepted. This is generally much appreciated on Stack Overflow. That way, credit goes to those that have helped you, and people who find your questions later on can quickly see whether they were solved or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`.children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) (to get *immediate* children) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) (which looks everywhere below) on the [`.parents()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) , for example:

```
(function ($) {
  $.SelectChildren = function (element) {
    $(element).parents().children(':checkbox').attr('checked', element.checked);
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Since you're passing a boolean, you can just use the `.checked` property directly as well.

[You can give it a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BgXrz/), the more traditional approach to get the same effect would look like this:

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
    $(this).parents().children(':checkbox').attr('checked', this.checked);
  });
});
```

[You can give that version a try here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/BgXrz/1/).

Comment: I'm having a little problem understanding your solution.  The answer you gave would work if you just had one of the child checkboxes selected.  However, if you have two children selected, when you go to uncheck one of the two children the parent should remain checked; however, that is not the case here.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
$(element).parents(":checkbox").attr('checked', false);
```

UPDATE.  This is wrong, see Nick's solution.

Comment: A checkbox has no children ;)

Comment: No, but they have parents still.

Comment: @mkoistinen - Your selector is finding parent/ancestor elements that *are* checkboxes.

Comment: @Nick, exactly.  The OP is asking "how would I unselect ONLY (all)parent checkboxes when un-checking a child".  I'm not exactly sure what question you are answering.

Comment: @mkoistinen - The parent check boxes are in `<li>` elements, which *are* parents, you need to get them, then find checkboxes immediately in *them* (as to not get other descendants).   Your answer/selector looks for checkbox **parents**, e.g. `<input type="checkbox">child elements here</input>`....this is never valid markup, checkboxes can't have children, so they can't *be* parents.

Answer (score 0):

Identify the parent will a specific class like "parent"

Then

```
$(".parent").attr("checked", false);
```

Very Simple

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to allow a checkbox to show/hide childer elements OR elements withint a DIV (or in this case a bootstrap group).

Step #1 - apply the class 'switch' to the checkbox
Make sure the checkbox id is set

Step #2 - for the element you want to hide/toggle add the class with chcekbox ID

```
// -------------------------
// Checkbox to toggle related input fields
// Checkbox control class = switch
// -------------------------
$('.switch').each(function() {
    var tItems = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + tItems).hide();
});
// Toggle elements
// <div class="control-group applied_before <-- checkbox ID">
$('.switch').change(function () {
    var tItems = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.' + tItems).toggle();
});
// -------------------------
// -------------------------


<fieldset>
    <legend>Criminal History</legend>   
    <div class="control-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="criminal_offender" id="criminal_offender" class="switch" />
        <label>criminal_offender</label>
    </div>

    <div class="control-group criminal_offender">
        <label>criminal_offense</label>
        <input type="text" name="criminal_offense" id="criminal_offense" />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group criminal_offender">
        <label>criminal_st_code</label>
        <input type="text" name="criminal_st_code" id="criminal_st_code" />
    </div>

    <div class="control-group criminal_offender">
        <label>criminal_date</label>
        <input type="text" name="criminal_date" id="criminal_date" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>  

            var checkParent  = function(ref) {
                return $(ref).parent().parent().parent().children().first();

            }

           $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
                if(this.checked){
                    $(this).parent().children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true);
                }

                else {
                    var a = checkParent(this);
                    while(a.length > 0 && a.prop("tagName") == "INPUT" )
                     {
                        a.attr("checked", false);
                        a = checkParent(a);

                    }

                }
           });

        </script>
```

Just completed this algorithm for a project and thought i'll share it on stack flow

Basically, if you check a parent, all the children are selected and when you uncheck a child, all the parents associated with it will be unnchecked because a Parent can remain checked only if all the children are checked

Make sure all the checkboxes are within li and all the li are within ul otherwise this won't work

sample html

```
<ul id="a">
        <ul id="b">
            <li id="parentli"><input type="checkbox" id="parent"> Parent
                <ul id="c">
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="aa">Child 1</li>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="ab">Child 2
                        <ul id="d">
                             <li><input type="checkbox" id="aba">Child 2-1</li>
                        </ul>
                     </li>
                     <li><input type="checkbox" id="ac">Child 3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>

   </ul>
```